# Printing max elements from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have a dataset which involves two columns- Query number and Complaint Type.
I wish to find the max 10 Complaint Types.
I have grouped the Complaints together.
How do i add all the Query Numbers against the Complaint Type and find the maximum of them?

```
#Finding Major Complaint types
NYC_Complaints = NYC_calls[['Query Number','Complaint Type']]
Complaints = NYC_Complaints.groupby('Complaint Type')
```

Comment: `.nlargest(10)`?